# Are Gigabit Rated Routers Really Useful in SOHO Environment?

Tags: wireless-router, adsl-router

I have a Wireless Dual Band Gigabit Router. The product is rated with Wifi speed of 300 Mbps.

1. Does this mean that router can send data at speed up to 300 Mbps through the air AND that to receive that data at that same speed, my PC must be equipped with a wireless adapter rated at 300 Mbps ?
2. If my PC wireless adapter is limited to 100 Mbps - does that mean that that is the maximum throughput I will get in data transfer ?
3. If my ISP is supplying download speed of 5 Mbps then what is the use of me buying the a router which has gigabit speed for each of its LAN ports ? With that kind of download speed (ie. 5 Mbps) I might as well buy 100 Mbps adapters - which are cheaper ??

I cannot see gigabit speed device offers any benefit if the internet speed offered by service providers do not reach gigabit per second speed.

The only benefit I can see is : I will get gigabit transfer speed between my local LAN devices when they are connected via cable to the LAN ports of the wireless router - but the NIC on my connected devices *must* also be rated as gigabit.

Is this the correct understanding ?

Comment: "Does this mean that router can send data at speed up to 300 Mbps through the air AND that to receive that data at that same speed, my PC must be equipped with a wireless adapter rated at 300 Mbps ?" - You will only get a potential 300 Mbps if you have a client connected that can support it (802.11ac router -> 802.11ac client) as an example.  "If my PC wireless adapter is limited to 100 Mbps - does that mean that that is the maximum throughput I will get in data transfer ?" - Yes.  "If my ISP is supplying download speed of 5 Mbps" - You are mixing up your units.....

Answer (score 1):

Your connection is only as strong as its weakest link.  From one point to another, the slowest speed is as fast as it can go.  So a gigabit router can transfer at gigabit speeds, but only to gigabit connected devices.  If your ethernet card as 100Mb, then the transfer speed will be 100Mbps.

Comment: Yes, but also, if you have a NAS with gigabit. It can serve more PCs at 100mb/s before bottlenecking out.